# Can a Generic Bluetooth Dongle be used for printing

Tags: printing

I have a Canon MFP and I wish to know is it possible for me to use my Android mobile and print to this printer using an USB Dongle from my system. What all are required for the printing?  I have a Canon Printer, System with Generic Radio USB Dongle, Canon driver installed and an app in my Android mobile printershare or Canon based application. How do I connect or link and print from my Android Samsung mobile?

Answer (score 0):

This sentence is fairly unclear "and an app in my android mobile printershare or cannon based application"

From that sentence, it appears you are interested in printing from the phone to the printer by any means, not just bluetooth.

If you don't already know, this can be accomplished by using Google's cloud print connector.
See [this](http://code.google.com/apis/cloudprint/docs/overview.html)

Particularly, the section on non-cloud printers. Note that this requires using a network connection and a piece of software on a desktop which can use the printer.

If this is not the solution to your problem, I recommend clarifying your question and its title.